# Bluemix IOT foundation Launch Dashboard keeps spinning on MAC (works on Windows)

Tags: macos, ibm-cloud, iot

I started the IOT Foundation service following the steps in Jeff Sloyer's tutorial on using a Raspberry Pi, Python, etc.  I start the IOT service, and I get the page to Launch Dashboard.  However, when I do this, it just spins.

I found the similar question where someone else hit a launch dashboard problem on a MAC where they got it working on another platform, so I tried it from Windows.  Windows is working fine.  But, I can't get the dashboard from my Mac, which is the laptop I want to work on.  The similar question had no resolution, and wouldn't let me add a comment to it, hence a new question.

Comment: Do you have options re. what Browser you use?  Might be OK on Firefox.

Comment: I just tested and got same results using Safari on Mac.  I thought this defect had been fixed, I will check with the dev status on status.

Comment: I have confirmed there is a defect open for this. The IoT dashboard should work on older Safari browsers, but a fix is required for the more recent versions and we hope to have that rolled out soon.

Answer (score 0):

There was a defect which has now been fixed and the IoT dashboard should work on safari browsers.